# sign app using given keystore

Tags: android, apk, keystore

I am enhancing an existing app launched over play store and now, I want to publish new version. Previous developer has given me keystore file. I can't proceed further to sign apk file.

I have generated .crt file using following command:

```
keytool -export -alias appname -file appname -keystore keystore
```

Then I try to import using following command:

```
keytool -import -alias appname -file appname.crt -keystore keystore
```

I am getting error as below:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate reply and certificate in keystore are identical
```

So, I deleted alias using following command:

```
keytool -delete -alias appname -keystore keystore
```

Then I try to reimport and it worked showing output such as below:

```
keytool -import -alias flavorsome -file flavorsome.crt -keystore keystore
Enter keystore password:
Owner: CN=Name, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknow
n
Issuer: CN=Name, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unkno
wn
Serial number: number
Valid from: Thu Jul 28 09:34:07 IST 2016 until: Mon Dec 14 09:34:07 IST 2043
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  md5:md5
         SHA1: A1:B1:C1
         SHA256: 00:00:00
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 08 EC 2B 67 A0 94 11 A0   BA 43 C9 8C DB A8 D1 61  ..+g.....C.....a
0010: 0E C4 68 29                                        ..h)
]
]

Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
```

Then I tried to sign the apk file and I am getting error as below:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1
withRSA -digestalg SHA1 release-unsigned.apk appname
Enter Passphrase for keystore:
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: appname.  appname must referen
ce a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public
key certificate chain.
```

**My main question is how can I proceed further to sign apk file with the given keystore file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have signed it using following command:

```
jarsigner release-unsigned.apk appname -keystore keystore
```

Then zipaligned it and generated apk file is allowed in play store.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate new .crt file if you have keystore file already.
May be https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-manually  be usefull.

Comment: Thanks but I am not using Android Studio but I tried with terminal, generated aligned apk file and then used apksigner.bat file and getting error as "Failed to load signer "signer #1": keystore does not contain key entries"